# Install Jupyter Notebook in Atom Error: Installing “jupyter-notebook@0.0.10” failed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, atom-editor

The jupyter notebook is available as a package inside the atom.
Below screenshot for package:

[image: jupyter in atom]

Unfortunately, when I press the install button I get the error message shown below :

> Installing “jupyter-notebook@0.0.10” failed

and the error detail is below shown when I press **`Show output…`**:

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /tmp/apm-install-dir-118110-11290-1g90s6g.50fjqq6w29/node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/bufferutil
>   node-gyp rebuild
>
> runas@3.1.1 install /tmp/apm-install-dir-118110-11290-1g90s6g.50fjqq6w29/node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/runas
>   node-gyp rebuild /tmp/apm-install-dir-118110-11290-1g90s6g.50fjqq6w29 └── (empty)

Please see the details of this issue below:

```
Installing “jupyter-notebook@0.0.10” failed.Hide output…
> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /tmp/apm-install-dir-118110-11148-k6dnh7.k94kzhyqfr/node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


> runas@3.1.1 install /tmp/apm-install-dir-118110-11148-k6dnh7.k94kzhyqfr/node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/runas
> node-gyp rebuild

/tmp/apm-install-dir-118110-11148-k6dnh7.k94kzhyqfr
└── (empty)


npm WARN deprecated jupyter-js-services@0.21.1: This package has moved to @jupyterlab/services
npm WARN deprecated phosphor@0.5.0: use @phosphor/ packages
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "/snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/python-interceptor.sh" is v3.6.3, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (/snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:454:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:443:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:197:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.13.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "/snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/apm-install-dir-118110-11148-k6dnh7.k94kzhyqfr/node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "/snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/python-interceptor.sh" is v3.6.3, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (/snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:454:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:443:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:197:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.13.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "/snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/apm-install-dir-118110-11148-k6dnh7.k94kzhyqfr/node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/runas
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/apm-install-dir-118110-11148-k6dnh7.k94kzhyqfr/package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-118110-11148-k6dnh7.k94kzhyqfr No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-118110-11148-k6dnh7.k94kzhyqfr No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-118110-11148-k6dnh7.k94kzhyqfr No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-118110-11148-k6dnh7.k94kzhyqfr No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bufferutil@1.2.1 (node_modules/jupyter-notebook/node_modules/bufferutil):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/home/User_name/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/home/User_name/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/tmp/d-118110-11148-wokfwx.il28dxi529/package.tgz" "--runtime=electron" "--target=1.6.15" "--arch=x64" "--global-style"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! runas@3.1.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the runas@3.1.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the runas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs runas
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls runas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/apm-install-dir-118110-11148-k6dnh7.k94kzhyqfr/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

My operating system:
 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Atom version: 1.23.3

Please how to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to ask a question... Please use the [edit] link below the question to add more information.

Comment: Done! thank you so much! I would appreciate if someone can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue while trying to install "jupyter-notebook" in atom, and the error message is quite clear:

```
Error: Python executable "/snap/atom/116/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/python-interceptor.sh" is v3.6.3, which is not supported by gyp
```

Which basically means that one of the dependencies of `jupyter-notebook` for atom is expecting another python version, namely « `Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0` ».

However, looking at [the package page](https://atom.io/packages/jupyter-notebook), support for `python3` seems possible, so I tried by followed the instructions :

1. first by installing dependencies: `pip3 install jupyter jupyter_kernel_gateway` then trying `apm install` --> same error.
2. second by getting source from their git repo, then `apm install; apm link` which returned no error. However, the package seems not installed in atom.

So, as I'd like to work with `python3` (even if I'll try to support `python2.7` afterward), basically I cannot install this atom package :-/